# logo wont showing on nav bar in html

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

in the below html file i tried adding logo to nav bar , but the logo wont appear when i run file. can anyone see what's wrong. i was folowing web development course in coursera .iam new to programing though.

**code**

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #61122f;
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
}

#header-nav {
  background-color: #f6b319;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 0;
}

#logo-img {
  background: url("https://www.crushpixel.com/big-static7/preview4/restaurant-logo-140120.jpg");
  height: 150px;
  margin: 10px 15px 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap 5.0.x -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- original markup -->
<header>
  <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="index.html" class="">
          <div id="logo-img" alt="logo image"></div>
        </a>
      </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: delete ``alt`` from ``div#logo-img``.

Comment: to eleborate above comment: the `alt attribute` is an attribute for the `<img>` tag only. Its purpose is to provide an alternative if the image cant be displayed and to give search engine crawlers and screen readers information about an image. It can not be used on a `div` element.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that you provide the relative width value by using width parameter and give parameter like "background-size: cover;" and "background-repeat: no-repeat;".

We can also insert an image to our website using 'background-image: url('path-name');' method.

```css
/* added CSS */
#logo-img {
  width: 100px;
}


/* original CSS */
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #61122f;
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
}

#header-nav {
  background-color: #f6b319;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 0;
}

#logo-img {
  background-image: url("https://www.crushpixel.com/big-static7/preview4/restaurant-logo-140120.jpg");
  height: 150px;
  margin: 10px 15px 10px 0;
  width: 200px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap 5.0.x -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- original markup -->
<header>
  <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="index.html" class="">
          <div id="logo-img" alt="logo image"></div>
        </a>
      </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You haven't added `width` to you're image(`div#logo-img`).
2. Don't forget to add these properties when you're trying to apply a background photo using `background` via CSS.

`background: url(foo) center/cover no-repeat;`

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #61122f;
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
}

#header-nav {
  background-color: #f6b319;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 0;
}

#logo-img {
  background: url("https://www.crushpixel.com/big-static7/preview4/restaurant-logo-140120.jpg") center/cover no-repeat;
  width:100px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 10px 15px 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap 5.0.x -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- original markup -->
<header>
  <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="index.html" class="">
          <div id="logo-img" alt="logo image"></div>
        </a>
      </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score -1):

The Issue is caused by the fact that you sue a abckground-image to include the image through CSS. An `anchor's` width is depending of the content. As you have no content included the width will be `0`. As such you need to give it a fixed width larger then 0.

```css
/* added CSS */
#logo-img {
  width: 100px;
}


/* original CSS */
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #61122f;
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
}

#header-nav {
  background-color: #f6b319;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 0;
}

#logo-img {
  background: url("https://www.crushpixel.com/big-static7/preview4/restaurant-logo-140120.jpg");
  height: 150px;
  margin: 10px 15px 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap 5.0.x -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- original markup -->
<header>
  <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="index.html" class="">
          <div id="logo-img" alt="logo image"></div>
        </a>
      </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

The smarter solution is:

Do not add the logo through CSS as background image. Use the `<img>` tag instead in HTML:

```css
/* added CSS */
#logo-img {
  height: 150px;
  margin: 10px 15px 10px 0;
  display: block;
}

/* original CSS */
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #61122f;
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
}

#header-nav {
  background-color: #f6b319;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap 5.0.x -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- original markup -->
<header>
  <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="index.html" class="">
          <img id="logo-img" src="https://www.crushpixel.com/big-static7/preview4/restaurant-logo-140120.jpg" alt="logo image">
        </a>
      </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```